# Cannot create a new file in the file manager on 17.10

Tags: files, gui

I have a problem since the update of Ubuntu 17.10

I cannot create a new file from the GUI. I have to create the files from the console.

[image: test folder]

[image: screenshot of terminal with test file highlighted]

Any idea?

[image: screenshot of file browser]

Comment: @pomsky, tested but not work! or so I misunderstood :/

Comment: Or probably "Templates" is not the correct folder name in you language, look for something already there in your `~/` which is equivalent to the English word "Templates" (modeles?).

Comment: According to Google Translate, it should be "Modèles"

Comment: Yeaaaah!!! Bingo =) https://i.imgur.com/Uxsg2Sw.png Big thanks to you two!!

Comment: @atmon3r Please remember to click the checkmark next to the answer!

Comment: @CharlesGreen  there is no button to validate it :/

Comment: @atmon3r Near the top of the answer, in the left column are an Up /Down arrow, and immediately below that is a check mark - the check mark is the 'accept' button.  The arrows are used to indicate that you think an answer is good or bad...